# SCSS can't override default variables if importing via es6-import syntax

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

Trying to override sass default variables in project (stack is about sass+babel+webpack, generated with vue-cli), but nothing is overridden. I use bootstrap, so if importing sass modules like

```
// in main.js
import './app_overrides.scss'
import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'
```

where **./app_overrides.scss** contains:

```
$def_color: #aaaaaa;
```

and **bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss** (for ex.):

```
$def_color: #ffffff !default;

h1 {
  color: $def_color;
}
```

h1 has finally default color `#ffffff` instead of overridden one. But if importing bootstrap scss-module directly in `./app_overrides.scss` via `@import` operator, everything works. The last one is inappropriate for me, as far as there is number of components in my project imported using es6-import syntax, all of them are using scss styling with possible bootstrap variable overrides, so I need to require bootstrap modules in the end of `main.js`.

May be there is some way to config webpack/sass to sort things right way?

Comment: Maybe this issue will help? https://github.com/uswds/uswds/issues/952

Comment: your code does not have to do with vue and webpack. remove unnecessary tags.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is well-known issue in WebPack+Sass projects. To solve this, all the shared variables and overrides should be exported to single file e.g. `variables.scss` and manually added to webpack config
[like described over there](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328#issuecomment-389510418):

```
// vue.config.js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: fs.readFileSync('src/variables.scss', 'utf-8')  //your-path-here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will inject `variables.scss` up to the header of each sass file in your project, so the variables described in variables.scss to become literally shared in between all the scss files. After the compilation into native css files all the sass variable definitions are to be gone.

Important: do not add any css descriptions into `variables.scss`, since after the rules compiled, they gonna be copy-pasted as many times as much stylesheet files you'll get on output.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your scss files bundle into one giant css file, the order of your files when you import them becomes essential.

Thus, you need to load your libraries first, then define your variables, mixins, animations, etc. and finally define your custom styles.

Comment: If vendor sass library contains overridable `!default` defined variables, then they should be overridden before importing vendor library. Even though that doesn't make the sence because if I imported some scss-stylesheet immediately after `import './app_overrides.scss'; import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';` like in my example above then none of sass variables defined in former two files are seen in the latter one. The variables are just not shared in between different scss files